# How to completly remove AWS SAM CLI and SAM CLI from ubuntu?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli, sam

a month ago I needed to install aws-sam on my pc. I don't remember what went wrong but I ended with 2 different version of sam installed in the same computer. And I know this because if I run `sam --version` inside the terminal I get this output:

```
A newer version of the AWS SAM CLI is available!
Your version:   0.2.11
Latest version: 1.0.0
See https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local for upgrade instructions

sam version 0.2.11
```

Instead if I type `sam --version` inside the terminal of Virtual Studio Code I get this output:

```
SAM CLI, version 0.53.0
```

(weird)

For the project I need to interact with I need the second version of sam (the one with 0.53.0).
I would like to remove both of them and do a clean install again.

Comment: One (older) probably is installed using pip. You can check `pip freeze | grep sam` or `pip3 freeze | grep sam`.  For brew `brew list --versions | grep aws`.

Comment: Yes, one is installed with pip3 and one with brew. I uninstalled the one with pip3. But now if I type ```sam --version``` in the console I get: ```bash: /home/dan/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.2/bin/sam: No such file or directory``` and I'm able to use sam (version 0.5) only inside visual studio code (this is very strange, I don't understand why..).

Comment: in the vscode, you can execute `which sam`. This should show where is the sam located. Then you can updated your `PATH` in `~/.bashrc` to the folder where `sam` is. When you login, logout, or source the .bashrc, you should be able to find the correct sam. By the way. If you don't mind I will make an answer about pip and brew for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments.

There are two `sam` packages, because one was installed using `pip3` and the other was installed using `brew`. This can be checked using the following commands:

```
pip3 freeze | grep sam

# and

brew list --versions | grep aws
```

To uninstall the `brew` version, the following command can be used:

```
brew uninstall aws-sam-cli
```

The change may require later adjustment/setting of `PATH` in `~/.bashrc` to correctly point to the remaining `sam` version's folder:

```
export PATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Can I ask what exactly should I write inside `~/.bashrc`?
I added ```export sam="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/sam"``` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Agilulfo I updated the answer. You will have to open new terminal, log out/in, or excute `source ~/.bashrc` for the PATH to be loaded.

Comment: That was useful - the issue was there was a python version of SAM installed as well.  This was on windows.